# Secure function evaluation

Tags: protocol-design, secret-sharing, multiparty-computation

> Consider 3 parties, Alice, Bob and Charlie. Suppose
>   each party has a bit as input, i.e. Alice, Bob and Charlie hold $a, b, c \in \{0, 1\}$ respectively.
>   Show how construct a scheme with which they can compute the function $f (a, b, c) = a \oplus b \oplus c$
>   such that the following are satisfied:
>
> (1) All parties learn $f(a, b, c)$ at the end.
>
> (2) No party can learn more about the other party's input than what they can infer from $f(a, b, c)$ and choosing their own input wisely.

My attempt: A chooses $r_1,r_2\in\{0,1\}$, B chooses $s_1,s_2,\in\{0,1\}$, and C chooses $t_1,t_2\in\{0,1\}$ randomly. Then dealer of respective secrets (bold) distribute 3 shares to each party in the following manner.

$A: \it{\bf{a\oplus r_1 \oplus r_2}}, s_1, t_1$

$B: r_1, \it{\bf{b\oplus s_1 \oplus s_2}}, t_2$

$C: r_2, s_2, \it{\bf{c\oplus t_1 \oplus t_2}}$.

To reconstruct the secret $a\oplus b\oplus c$, they can compute their sum of shares,

$A: (a\oplus r_1 \oplus r_2)\oplus s_1\oplus t_1$

$B: r_1\oplus( b\oplus s_1 \oplus s_2)\oplus t_2$

$C: r_2\oplus s_2\oplus( c\oplus t_1 \oplus t_2)$.

Comment: Looks like HW...how have you already tried to approach this problem?

Comment: @DrLecter I have edited my question.

Comment: Ok, but from your description it is not clear who gives which values to whom :/ the A, B and C refers to the parties I guess, but that does not make sense yet. All should be able to compute $f$

Comment: Your current method suggests to be you've slightly misunderstood the question. $a,b,c$ are created by A,B and C respectively. The protocol you describe requires them to be known in advance by some 4th party, which does not exist in the scenario given.

Comment: @freak_warrior I guess in the last step you mean compute and publish their sum of shares. Yes, then it works and A B and C can compute $f(a\oplus b \oplus c)$ without learning the other's inputs.

Comment: Is $f(a,b,c)=a+b+c$ or $a\oplus b\oplus c$?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter if you work in $Z_2$ ($\oplus$) or in $Z_n$ ($+$) for any $n>2$. This approach always works. But yes, in the question $+$ should be $\oplus$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your protocol is good (assuming an honest-but-curious adversary model). As DrLecter pointed out, each party will need to publish their sum of shares. To recover the answer, each party then simply xors all published values.